# Is it possible to make a smart ternary operator to return a complex value if a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, php, excel-formula

Apologies for the vague Title. I have no idea how to word the question!

In both PHP and JS I come across situations where I want to return a value but only if it meets a criteria. I was wondering if there is shorter way that I have not discovered yet?

---

**Example: if complexFunction() >= 0 then return its value else return zero**

The complexFunction() return value may be used in multiple places in different ways so I do not want to include the condition in the function itself

`return (complexFunction() >= 0 ? complexFunction() : 0);`

*//inefficient - calls function twice*

```
$value = complexFunction();
return ($value >= 0 ? $value : 0);
```

*//takes 2 lines and creates a variable*

`return (complexFunction() ? >= 0 : 0);`

*//ideal - complexFunction is only executed once, no variable is manually assigned and only one line used*

---

**This also would help in Excel:**

`=if(sum(ComplexRange) > 1000, sum(ComplexRange), 1000)`

*//inefficient - performs complex process twice*

`=if(HelperColumnSum > 1000, HelperColumnSum, 1000)`

*//increases size of sheet*

`=returnifconditionelse(sum(ComplexRange), ">1000", 1000)`

*//ideal - no helpercolumn or repeated calculation*

Comment: Not sure exactly what the function may return so it's difficult to tell, but `max(complexFunction(), 0)` ensures the value doesn't go -ve.

Comment: You cannot make the ternary operator do anything other than what it already does.

Comment: The overhead of the temporary variable is negligible, it will evaporate once the `return` executes.

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen. That's exactly what I what looking for. PHP, JS and Excel all have the max and min functions so I'll be using that from now on

Answer (score 2):

You could take a max value of either zero or the result of the call of `complexFunction`.

```
return Math.max(complexFunction(), 0);
```

Comment: Elegant enough. It's a performance trade-off between the function call overhead and the end-of-function temporary variable, but assuming this isn't called oodles of times...

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact possible to rig this into a ternary operator construct, as long as you have your brackets in the right places. Here's a sample implementation:

```
function complexer()
{
    // tweak the return value to test.
    return -1;
}


function returner()
{
    return (($x = complexer()) > 0 ? $x : 0);
}

echo returner(); // yields positive value or 0.
```

In the `returner` function above, the value of `complexer` is assigned to `$x`, its outcome is evaluated, and then either `$x` or `0` is returned.

*Why does that work?* In PHP, an assignment yields the assigned value to its leftward statement; `echo $a = 8` would output `8`, etc., and `if ($a = false)` would evaluate as false, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I must remember that assignments also return the assigned value. I don't think it's something I've ever used!

Comment: It can be handy at times. Though some view it bad practice (because some struggle telling the difference between `=` and `==`), I often find it convenient to assign in a condition check; e.g. `if ($x = mayReturnPositive()) { $y = foobar($x); } elseif ($x = FirstFallback() { $y = (int) $x; }` etc., streamlines things a notch.